# I'm having problems loading objects from disk in Java

Tags: java, serialization, load, save, instantiation

I'm creating a system to save and load objects from disk. I made a `Savable` interface that includes methods to read and write data, and that works correctly. Anything in my program that needs to be saved can implement this interface and use it to save and read whatever data they need to work with. The problem lies in actually creating the objects when reading them from disk. Right now, I save the class name of the objects, and then when reading them I instantiate them using `Class.forName(savedClassName).newInstance();`. The problem with this is it requires any `Savable` class to have a no-argument constructor, but there is no way to force that in the interface itself. So if I, or someone working with me, tries to create a Savable object but forgets to include a no-arg constructor, there's going to be exceptions way down the line, and we very likely won't even discover them for a long time. I am at a loss to solve this problem, since it seems there is no way to use an interface to require a predictable way to construct an object.

Comment: Have you tried with an Abstract class instead (or plus) the Interface?

Comment: Any reason why you didn't go with Serializable and an Object input/output stream?

Comment: @Martin: An Abstract class would be pretty restrictive (no other class hierarchies allowed)

Comment: @Martin I don't understand how using an abstract class would solve my problem.

Comment: @Ash, it depends on what they really need. If they need to be flexible with hierarchies, then they will have to check another solution.

Comment: @Techni, I don't like posting other post as an answer, but take a look at this option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759457/require-a-default-constructor-in-java, specially the first answer...

Comment: @Techni, you can define the default constructor in the abstract class, check the answer I posted, maybe it can help... The other approach is to build some workaround as in the post I suggested in the previous comment. The fact is that you cannot solve the problem by the interface itself, you need to look for another architectural design (if it suits you) or implement some workaround.

Comment: @Ash I like to have control over exactly what data is saved, and where, and the format in which it is saved. That way I could conceivably write other tools to interact with it or something. Plus it's a good exercise since I'm doing this project for fun anyway. And I don't like how in the standard serialization everything is saved by default, and you have to specify which things are not to be saved. I think it should be the other way round.

Comment: @Techni: Fair enough. If you haven't already, you may want to look at the Data Access Object pattern/idea/technique as well, it might be of interest.

Comment: @Ash Looks like I was sort of using the DAO pattern without even knowing about it! Cool!

Answer (score 0):

How about disallowing classes without a default constructor, to be saved.  That way the only class anyone will ever try to load is one which has been saved and hence therefore one which has a default constructor.

Comment: That's a good way to reduce the possible damage, but it still doesn't solve the problem that you have to just remember to include a no-args constructor every time you implement Savable.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially create an Abstract Unit test that tests for the presence of the default constructor (and nothing else) and inherit your unit tests from that, this is probably less restrictive than an abstract class in you hierarchy and this should indicate that the Constructor is missing.